# How to multply an scalar with a defined variable (\def) in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I currently have the following working code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\myr{7}
      \def\mytheta{45}         
      \def\myphi{50}
      \def\px{{\myr*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi)}}
      \def\py{{\myr*sin(\mytheta)*sin(\myphi)}}                    
      \def\pz{{\myr*cos(\mytheta)}}

      \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1.2*\myr,0,0) node[left]{$x$};                    
      \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2*\myr,0) node[right]{$y$};
      \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2*\myr) node[right]{$z$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem starts when I replace `1.2*\myr` for `1.2*\px` in the first of the `\draw` lines. I tried writing `{1.2*\px}` but it didn't solve the problem. I also tried adding `cm` and `pt` at the end of `1.2*\px` without sucess. How can I solve this? Thanks for reading!

### Solved

The problem was solved by removing the `{}` around the definition of `\px, \py, \pz` and replacing `1.2*\myr` for `{1.2*\px}`.

Better way to solve it:
adding `declare function = {px = \myr*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi);}` inside the `[]` of `\begin{tikzpicture}` and then just writing `1.2*px`.

Comment: Don't add another set of `{}` around the definitions of `\px`, `\py` and `\pz`. PGFMath uses those to detect an array which you don't want. You will still need `{1.2*\px}`, though.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Solved! Thank you!

Comment: That said, you can also `declare function = { px = \myr*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi); }` and use `1.2*px` (which would also help if px contains a `+` or `-` because you don't have to remember doing `1.2*(\px)`). There's also the [`perspective` library](https://tikz.dev/library-perspective) and [`tikz-3dplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) for more 3d-ness.

Comment: That's so much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the pair of `{}` around your definition. PGFMath assumes an array here. You will still need `{1.2*\px}`.
2. Use `declare function` so that you only have to use `1.2*px` (though I'm using `myPx` in the code below).
3. Set the *x*, *y* and *z* length of the *xyz* coordinate system accordingly and then you can just use `(1.2, 0, 0)`.

*Note:* For more 3D in TikZ there's

- the [`3d` library](https://tikz.dev/library-3d),
- the [`perspective` library](https://tikz.dev/library-perspective) and
- the [`tikz-3dplot` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style=->]
\def\myr{7}
\def\mytheta{45}
\def\myphi{50}
\def\px{\myr*sin(\mytheta)*cos(\myphi)}
\def\py{\myr*sin(\mytheta)*sin(\myphi)}
\def\pz{\myr*cos(\mytheta)}

\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- ({1.2*\px},0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,{1.2*\py},0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,{1.2*\pz}) node[below left]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  axis/.style=->,
  declare function={
    myR = 7; myTheta = 45; myPhi = 50;
    px(\radius,\theta,\phi) = \radius*sin(\theta)*cos(\phi);
    py(\radius,\theta,\phi) = \radius*sin(\theta)*sin(\phi);
    pz(\radius,\theta,\phi) = \radius*cos(\theta);
    myPx = px(myR, myTheta, myPhi);
    myPy = py(myR, myTheta, myPhi);
    myPz = pz(myR, myTheta, myPhi);}]
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1.2*myPx,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2*myPy,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2*myPz) node[below left]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  axis/.style=->,
  my cs/.style n args={3}{
    x={1cm*(#1)*sin(#2)*cos(#3)},
    y={1cm*(#1)*sin(#2)*sin(#3)},
    z={-.385cm*(#1)*cos(#2)}},
  my cs={7}{45}{50}]
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1.2, 0,   0  ) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,   1.2, 0  ) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,   0,   1.2) node[below left]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]